# Negative Margin Adds Unwanted 1px Extra Spacing

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML and CSS

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is that 1px extra spacing on the left, between the inner and outer div, coming from?

Change the negative margin to -11px, and it works as it should (no gaps).

You can also remove all the margins and compare with the "negative + positive" scenario above, to see how the two are not the same.

Thank you.

---

### **EDIT**

**After figuring it out, I just wanted to share the below in case helpful to future visitors.**

1. The inner div is back to the exact spot it was when it started, after applying the -/+10px. It is just that the border that used to be in between the *content edge* of the body element, and the *margin edge* of the inner div (i.e. outer div's border) has shifted 10px to the left together with outer div. Thus, it works as it should without any oddities.
2. Margins of a child box naturally apply from the *content edge* of its parent box. That is how the *box model* should work. It is not possible to change that behavior with `box-sizing: border-box`
3. Possible solutions to the eliminate gap include (but are not limited to):

   - Converting the CSS to SCSS, storing the border width in a variable and subtracting that variable from parent's margin. (It was not necessary to convert to SCSS and use a variable, but it make the style sheet much easier to maintain and update.)
   - Eliminating the need for a negative margin altogether with JavaScript
   - Using outline instead of border on the parent div

Comment: because of the border. with `box-sizing: border-box` it will not work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with the `.outer` border. You can see below that when the red border is moved `10px` to the left, there is a gap where it would have been if it wasn't moved to the left (when the margin is `0`).

And because the `.inner` div is relative to the `.outer` div, it doesn't 'fill up' that `1px` gap it creates by moving `.outer` 10 pixels to the left.

Here you can see the gap. (It looks like 2 pixels because the page is zoomed in by 200%)

[image]

---

### **Edit with extra info:**

Extra "proof" to show that the extra space comes from the `.outer` div,
if you remove the `1px` width of the `.outer` border, you also remove the gap:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it exactly has to do with outer border, child/parent relationship...

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment to StefanDimi's post below. Will think about what you said and see if I can get it to compute. It is still not clear to me exactly why we are not back to square one.

Comment: @Magnus I updated my answer with some extra information, I think it would make it clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for wrong answer, i was writing in a rush... the math:

```
(-10pxMargin + 10pxMargin + 1pxBorder) = 1
```

you need

```
(-11pxMargin + 10pxMargin + 1pxBorder) = 0
```

let me know if this is clear enough, the thing is that margin doesnt include borders.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for an exact walk-through of the mechanics and the math, showing how we end up with the 1px whitespace gap.

Comment: Yes, i walked you through the exact math there:)(there is no special math there, you just had an extra pixel there because of the border), but SirExotic went a bit more in depth, so thats pretty much all there is to be said about this. Cheers

Comment: Hmmmm. It is not clear to me. The outer div is moved 10px to the left (in relation to the body element's content box). That will move all its content along with it). Then we push the inner div 10px to the right again, in relation to the outer div's content box (which was shifted exactly 10px to the left). Thus you should end up where you started.

Comment: I completely messed up, i am changing the answer right now with the explanation, its only because of the border, so you are doing this math^^

Comment: And one more thing, removing the left border will fix that, but you dont want to remove borders, lets assume they are there for a reason, you dont see them since the left margin is -10 and body margin is 8px so its out of the view, and you cant see that removing left border makes difference.

Comment: Ugh, I just got it. The inner element's block box is actually back at the exact place it started in my original code, after the -/+10px. It's just that the part that used to be between the body element's left content edge and the outer div's margin edge (i.e. the border) is shifted.

Comment: I wonder if setting outer div to border-box will work. Will test when I get home. Perhaps the inner div then calculates it's margin from outer div's left margin edge, instead of it's left content edge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170714/discussion-between-stefandimi-and-magnus).

Answer (score 1):

That extra pixel is from the `.outer` element.

```css
.outer {

  margin-left: -10px;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please walk through the exact mechanics of it? I.e. what box is affected by each margin, and how we end up with the 1px whitespace gap.

Comment: This is not a solution, this is removing a border that was there for a reason i would assume, Its the relationship between parent and child div thats a problem...

Comment: The original question is "Where is that 1px extra spacing on the left, between the inner and outer div, coming from?" I answer that, the other answers went more in detail

Comment: Sorry brother, didnt know that that was the original question. but still, i was referring to the fact that removing the border isnt the solution since that border is there for a specific reason, it is adding one more negative pixel to the left(if im not mistaken) since the margin doesnt include border.

Comment: Yep, your math is correct there. All of the answers look good.. Just a matter of what helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `border` fothe outer element. You can use `outline` for it.

```css
.outer {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```